# Laravel Eloquent Model Attributes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

After instantiating a model class that extends Laravel's Eloquent Model class, is there a way to determine if the property/attribute maps to the table, and therefore can be saved to the table?

For example, I have a table `announcements` with columns `id`, `text` and "created_by".

How can I know `created_by` is an attribute and will be saved if set?

```
$announcement = new Announcement();
```

`isset($announcement->created_by)` understandably returns false if I haven't explicitly set the value yet. I have tried various functions inherited from the Eloquent model class, but so far none have worked. I'm looking for something like:

`$announcement->doesThisMapToMyTable('created_by')` that returns true whether or not `$announcement->created_by` has been set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Laravel 5.4:

```
$hasCreatedAt = \Schema::hasColumn(app(Model::class)->getTable(), 'created_at');

    if($hasCreatedAt == true) {
       ...
    }
```

Comment: Yes, so nice and simple. Everybody using Laravel 5.4 should upvote this answer.

Answer (score 37):

If your model is filled with data, you can:

```
$announcement = Announcement::find(1);

$attributes = $announcement->getAttributes();

isset($attributes['created_by']);
```

For empty models (new Models), unfortunately you will have to get the columns using a small hack. Add this method to your BaseModel:

```
<?php

class BaseModel extends Eloquent {

    public function getAllColumnsNames()
    {
        switch (DB::connection()->getConfig('driver')) {
            case 'pgsql':
                $query = "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '".$this->getTable()."'";
                $column_name = 'column_name';
                $reverse = true;
                break;

            case 'mysql':
                $query = 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM '.$this->getTable();
                $column_name = 'Field';
                $reverse = false;
                break;

            case 'sqlsrv':
                $parts = explode('.', $this->getTable());
                $num = (count($parts) - 1);
                $table = $parts[$num];
                $query = "SELECT column_name FROM ".DB::connection()->getConfig('database').".INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'".$table."'";
                $column_name = 'column_name';
                $reverse = false;
                break;

            default: 
                $error = 'Database driver not supported: '.DB::connection()->getConfig('driver');
                throw new Exception($error);
                break;
        }

        $columns = array();

        foreach(DB::select($query) as $column)
        {
            $columns[$column->$column_name] = $column->$column_name; // setting the column name as key too
        }

        if($reverse)
        {
            $columns = array_reverse($columns);
        }

        return $columns;
    }

}
```

Extend your model from it:

```
class Announcement extends BaseModel {

}
```

Then you will be able to:

```
$columns = $announcement->getAllColumnsNames();

isset($columns['created_by']);
```

Comment: Thanks, but both $announcement->attributes and $announcement->getAttributes() return NULL.

Comment: Yeah, on empty models you don't have access to them, so I just added a method I use in my apps.

Comment: The use of isset() gave me problems on my Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS with PHP 5.5.

Comment: This works provided I replace `$this->table` with `$this->getTable()`. If you could make that change, I'll mark this answer as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: @sidneydobber, how did you get around your "isset" issue on ubuntu? I'm actually having the same problem now. The array clearly has the key when I do the var_dump() but "isset" is returning false. Weird.

Comment: Nice, @crowfoot, my models has a published $table property, sorry about that. Just edited.

Comment: Ok. Brain fart. isset() won't work unless we change the line from `$columns[] = $column->$column_name` to `$columns[$column_name] = $column->$column_name`. (The array value is being set, but not the key).

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what you are trying to do. In your questio you say "is there way to determine if the property/attribute maps to the table?". But if you try to use it as an object (->) and the column does not exists in the database, it will give you an error. So, please, share some more code so we can see what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Antonio. I'm pretty much all set. With your help, I have this working locally. The last piece is that your code doesn't yet return the column name as a key. It returns $columns[0]['created_by'] and not $columns['created_by'] = 'whatever'. With that in mind, isset() doesn't work, but if you change `$columns[] = $column->$column_name` to `$columns[$column_name] = $column->$column_name` then isset() will work b/c the array now has $columns['created_by']... does that make sense?

Comment: Oh! Got it. I just edited to set the column name as key `$columns[$column->$column_name] = $column->$column_name;`

Comment: I can't tell if I should be happy that his hack worked or worried that I had to use a hack like this to get Laravel to do what I needed it to. Either way thanks for the tip!

Comment: To provide columns in models, Zend framework queries DB and uses caching to keep columns, Yii generates an awesome model with hard coded array (Gii tool) and Laravel makes you query db to get them each time! I definitely go for hard coding them in my model

Answer (score 14):

Rather than writing your own lookup into the database internals, you can just use the [`Schema` facade](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Schema.html) to look up the columns:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

$announcement = new Announcement();
$column_names = Schema::getColumnListing($announcement->getTable());
if (in_array('created_by', $column_names)) {
  // whatever you need
}
```

Alternatively, as early as [Laravel 4](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#checking-existence) there's the `hasColumn()` check:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

$announcement = new Announcement();
if (Schema::hasColumn($announcement->getTable(), 'created_by')) {
  // whatever you need
}
```

Comment: actually use in_array('created_by',$column_names) because created_by would be an array value this is in laravel 7

Comment: @user2293554 went back and double-checked on some older Laravel versions as I thought it was indexed with the columns similar to the other answer, but looks like not! Have updated my answer to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.4

I used Leiths answer to create generic helper method, which automatically maps JS-object to Laravel model (and basically ignores those properties which are not part of model, thus avoiding QueryBuilder error messages for undefined columns). Additionally contains simple createOrEdit -approach (even though doesn't have "does ID exist?" -validation):

```html
    public function store(Request $request) {
        if($request->input("club")) {
            $club = \App\Club::find($request->input("club")["id"]);
        } else {
            $club = new \App\Club;
        }
        $club = self::mapModel($request->input("club"), $club);
        $club->save();
    }
    
    public function mapModel($input,$model) {
        $columns = Schema::getColumnListing($model->getTable());
        foreach ($columns as $i => $key) {
            if($input[$key]) {
                $model->{$key} = $input[$key];
            }
        }
        return $model;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is very old but there is an even simpler answer that doesn't require querying the columns of the table on which the model is based.

If you are using standard timestamp columns in the models where you use them, you can use the following to determine if the 'created_at' column exists:

```php
$model->usesTimestamps();
```

If you are using a non-standard name for the created column, you would need to additionally get the name of that column using:

```php
$model->getCreatedAtColumn();
```

Answer (score -2):

I used to `!empty($announcement->created_by)` and it's work great for my